# How to center both vertical and horizontal inside a UIStackView

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uikit, uistackview

I have a simple **UIImageView** with **50x50 size**.
If I had a UIView of size 100x100 and I wanted to center the image inside of it, all I have to do is set these
[image]

But how do I do the same with a **UIStackView of size 100x100**?

**EDIT** i think i should have been more clear. The questions is, how do i center the image both vertically & horizontally inside of the UIStackview ?

Comment: Same procedure can be done to stackView as it is a subclass of UIView

Comment: you have only image view inside stackview

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Use two stack views.

Vertical stack view with centre alignment.

Inside that is a horizontal stack view with centre alignment t.

Inside that is your image.

Comment: Brillant! works well

Answer (score 11):

You need to set the alignment to center inside attribute inspector of `UIStackView`

[image]

Comment: The question asks how to centre vertically and horizontally.

Comment: @Fogmeister Then just add leading and trailing constraints with i.e. 16 pt and set priority to Greater or Equal. That's all for horizontal stackView. For vertical you should set top & bottom constraints accordingly.

Comment: @MykhailoLysenko uistackview is there so that you don’t have to mess around with so many auto layout constraints. Nested stack views are suggested and recommended by Apple. And adding a vertical stack view inside a horizontal stack view is perfectly fine for centring vertically and horizontally.

Comment: @Fogmeister any stackView is a UIView subclass that leads to take some graphic memory. And constraint is an NSObject sublclass and takes only either a few values and references to view or string of visual format. It's like you may add many sublayers onto a view (i.e. drawing custom borders) but it would be better to draw them withing CGPath that is just an array of points. BTW it's not hard and tricky to add those 2 constraints and that is more lightweight for an app. And if you finally count all those improvements you'll find out constraints to be a better approach.

Comment: @MykhailoLysenko UIStackView is not a rendered view and does not take up any graphics memory. It is not like a transparent layer etc... it is there to be used as a layout device. Much like constraints.

Answer (score 0):

Check attribute inspector for stackview settings:

[image]

Answer (score -3):

follow these steps.

1) drag Uiimageview.

[image]

2) click on UIimageview. Press Ctrl and drag downward or sidewise to parent view.
[image]

3) click on "centre vertically in view" and centre "horizontally in view"

4) then set height and width like below.
[image]

Thats it. your imageview will be at centre regardless of the device type. 
good luck.

leave a comment if you any question. Accept the answer if it helps you.

Comment: i think i should have been more clear. The questions is, how do i center the image both vertically & horizontally inside of the UIStackview ?

Comment: May be i didnt get your question right. but UIStackview also work as a normal view. you can apply these steps even if UIImage is inside a UIStackView. you can position it with respect to any parent view with same steps. drag UIImage to UIStackview and click centre horizontally and vertically. it will align the UIImage in the centre of stackview. but before that you have to apply constraints to UIStackView.

Comment: The whole point of using StackView is that you don't need to use constraints inside the stack view. If you're using constraints (for anything other than height and width) inside the stack view then you shouldn't be using a stack view. The way to centre like this with stack views is to use nested stack views. One for the horizontal centre and one for the vertical centre.

Comment: the question was center inside UIStackView!!