# How to vertically center a group of labels relative to an image?

Tags: ios, autolayout

This is what I want to achieve:

[image]

I want the image to be vertically centered in the cell and the two labels (which are placed inside another view) to be vertically centered relative to the image (as a group - this is why they are in a view).

Below is my attempt:

The second label has a lower content hugging value. As you can see, when there is a small text, because of the content hugging, the text in the second label wouldn't be placed directly under the first one, thus having a lot of empty space. Also, the first label should be placed lower.

[image]

When there is enough text, it looks good.
[image]

How should I treat the case when the text is small?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used the other suggestions to use a stack view plus the accepted answer here to make the alignment of the labels work: [How to center both vertical and horizontal inside a UIStackView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45406910/how-to-center-both-vertical-and-horizontal-inside-a-uistackview) .I don't touch the content hugging priority.

First I set up a **horizontal stack view** that will serve as a container. I pin it to the **Top, Bottom, Leading** and **Trailing** ends of the cell. Its size will be the size of the cell. Its **alignment** is **center**. It means it will center its components **vertically**. The **distribution** is **Fill** - the components will take the whole space **horizontally**.

[image: Content Stack View plus other constraints]

I put an image view and a **vertical stack view** as its components. I set up the image view with fixed height and width. I guessed this is what is wanted. I put the two labels as components of this second stack view.
The vertical stack view has **alignment Fill**. It will fill all space **horizontally**. The **distribution** is also **Fill**. It will fill all space **vertically**, but this space is intrinsic and set by the labels as far as I understand it. So it will grow and shrink with their content.

[image: Vertical Stack View plus other constraints]

And that’s it if I have understood the requirements correctly.

One more thing. Since I see that the text in the last picture you posted is cut at some point - if this is what you want, set one height constraint at the second label, that is less or equal than some number you choose, so the label cannot grow beyond it.

Answer (score 1):

Try to set your group of labels and image from stack view.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18929665)

Comment: For earning reputation you must have to comment on post. By the way thanks for you interference and becoming a guide book.

Answer (score 0):

A `UIStackView` will let you do exactly that.

In the case of few lines of text you have two options.
First, wrap the `UILabel` in another `UIStackView` and set the axis to Horizontal and the Alignment to Top.

If that doesn't do the trick check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1054558/vertically-align-text-to-top-within-a-uilabel) thread about vertically aligning a label.

Comment: Well, I tried it with the same result. You are still forced to set a different content hugging/compression value.